# The requested resource is not found. in IIS 10 on HTTP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-10

I've been stuck on a problem for hours already but I'm trying to make my Website available locally through IIS.
For some reason I am getting an HTTP error 404. [(image) The requested resource is not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv29t.png)

It is working if I use  [(image) https://localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMihD.png) and
[(image) http://{ipaddress}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvNVq.png)

I already Added my [(image) bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EoDM.png)
but apparently it still doesnt work when I use ip address instead of localhost..

Can somebody please help me :(

Comment: Can I see your web.config file ?

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi This is what i have right now

Comment: <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\Debug\net6.0\WebApi.WebApi.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" />
        </environmentVariables>

Comment: You can access this site and face 404 error, it means your application is working well. And the issue related to configurations in your code.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: Could you try to add the site bindings like type: HTTPS , hostname: keep it blank, port number : 443, ip address: *

Comment: are you using the public ip address to access your site outside of the network ?

Comment: What you got initially is expected because that matched your site bindings. If you don't know how to interpret bindings, run a report and it will teach you, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `Program.cs`(.Net6) or `Startup.cs`(.Net5-).

You need to delete `if (env.IsDevelopment())` this condition. Or change your code like below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // this condition is the root cause
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "EF_API v1"));
    }
    // default, no below code
    else {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "EF_API v1"));
    }
    ...
}
```